# ¿como añadir nuevas imagenes a las ya existentes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con ruby on rails que sirva galerías de imágenes, cada galería tiene entre 500 y 1000 imágenes, y pesa bastante, por lo que al desplegarla en el servidor, me veo con la limitación de que no puedo subir mas de 100mb. Lo que había pensado era crear las galerías por tramos, ir subiendo las imágenes de a pocos, pero cuando utilizo el método update del controlador, lo que me hace es editar la galería, eliminando las imágenes ya subidas y mostrando las nuevas.

Para la gestión de imágenes no utilizo ninguna gema, lo hago con la opción que da rails 6, con active_storage.

Por ahora no hay nada especial, el controlador está como se genera, no le he realizado ningún cambio en la parte de actualizar/editar y en el modelo solo he añadido el `has_many_attached :images` para que guarde multiples imagenes.

La pregunta, entonces, es, como sería la forma de poder añadir las nuevas imágenes sin borrar las anteriores??

Este es el controlador:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /albums/1 or /albums/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @album.update(album_params)
        format.html { redirect_to albums_path, notice: "Album was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @album }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_album
      @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:title, :date_event, :password, images: [])
    end
```

el schema.db:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_03_16_193227) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.string "service_name", null: false
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_variant_records", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.string "variation_digest", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id", "variation_digest"], name: "index_active_storage_variant_records_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "albums", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.date "date_event"
    t.string "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "role", default: ""
    t.string "name"
    t.string "passwd_album"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "province"
    t.integer "cod_postal"
    t.integer "phone"
    t.date "birthdate"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "active_storage_variant_records", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
end
```

Comment: ¿que gema usas para guardar las imágenes? Aparte podrías compartir código relevante, lo que muestras no dice mucho de como se guardan las imágenes en ese modelo Album.

Comment: @AlterLagos he editado un poco la pregunta y añadido código por si amplía mas info, referente a la gema, no uso gema, lo hago a través de active_storage, apenas estoy empezando el desarrollo, y como me he visto con este 'bloqueo' pues como que no he avanzado ni cambiado nada, o casi nada de código de como lo genera el scaffold

Comment: No he tenido tiempo de darte una respuesta completa pero antes de cerrar mi tab (lol) quiero ayudarte y decirte que primero que nada, tu estas utilizando el metodo de `update` que significa que es para _actualizar_, no crear nuevas imagenes. En segundo lugar, cuando hagas deployment a un servidor, es mejor que utilices Amazon S3, Google Cloud, o Microsoft Azure. Te recomiendo que leas la guia oficial: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no sabría cómo ayudarte para que lo hagas con Active Storage, pero, por experiencia propia, te recomiendo usar alguna API que se ocupe del problema, como por ejemplo: cloudinary.com/

Es super intuitivo y tiene más de un video explicativo. Además, probablemente lo más conveniente es volver a crear la aplicación explicitando que no quieres que se instale Active Storage (dependiendo del costo en tiempo, obvio).

Espero te sirva!